# how to install wine 0.9.52 using the terminal

Tags: wine, software-installation

How do I install wine 0.9.52? I prefer using the Ubuntu software centre alongside the terminal instead of actually downloading the files.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It is unlikely to be available in a PPA or the official repositories. That release it at least 5 years old. You can use PlayOnLinux, if the particular software you're looking to run has POL profile.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the following code in the terminal it should install the latest version of wine it can find or update your wine:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

This should work.